# python changes values of list

Tags: python, list, graph

I am fairly new to Python so please be patient, this is probably simple. I am trying to build an adjacency list representation of a graph. In this particular representation I decided to use list of lists where the first value of each sublist represents the tail node and all other values represent head nodes. For example, the graph with edges `1->2, 2->3, 3->1, 1->3` will be represented as `[[1,2,3],[2,3],[3,1]]`.

Running the following code on this edge list, gives a problem I do not understand.

The edge list (`Example.txt`):

```
1 2
2 3
3 1
3 4
5 4
6 4
8 6
6 7
7 8
```

The Code:

```
def adjacency_list(graph):

graph_copy = graph[:]
g_tmp = []
nodes = []
for arc in graph_copy:

    choice_flag_1 = arc[0] not in nodes
    choice_flag_2 = arc[1] not in nodes
    if choice_flag_1:
        g_tmp.append(arc)
        nodes.append(arc[0])
    else:
        idx = [item[0] for item in g_tmp].index(arc[0])
        g_tmp[idx].append(arc[1])

    if choice_flag_2:
        g_tmp.append([arc[1]])
        nodes.append(arc[1])

return g_tmp


# Read input from file
g = []
with open('Example.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line_split = line.split()
        new_line = []
        for element in line_split:
            new_line.append(int(element))
        g.append(new_line)
print('File Read. There are: %i items.' % len(g))
graph = adjacency_list(g)
```

During runtime, when the code processes arc `6 7` (second to last line in file), the following lines (found in the `else` statement) append `7` **not only** to `g_tmp` **but also** to `graph_copy` and `graph`.

```
idx = [item[0] for item in g_tmp].index(arc[0])
g_tmp[idx].append(arc[1])
```

What is happening?

Thank you!

J

P.S. I'm running Python 3.5

P.P.S. I also tried replacing `graph_copy = graph[:]` with `graph_copy = list(graph)`. Same behavior.

Comment: Why are you using list of lists? Adjacency list can be  represented by built in dictionary in python.

Comment: Tried graph.copy?

Comment: I ran the code and this thing didn't happen. Could you please provide more information about your problem. Probably some debug output when the `graph` and `graph_copy` change.

Comment: `graph[:]` only makes a shallow copy. `graph` and `graph_copy` are sharing all their elements.

Comment: Thank you everyone. problem was solved by the answer below. Thank you John, I will definitely try representation with dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the lines

```
   if choice_flag_1:
       g_tmp.append(arc)
```

When you append arc, you are appending a shallow copy of the inner list. Replace with a new list like so

```
   if choice_flag_1:
      g_tmp.append([arc[0],arc[1]])
```